# how to set excel column names (headings) dynamically in laravel?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

This is my excel columns

```
$excel_array[$i]['id'] = $value['id'];
$excel_array[$i]['name'] = $value['name'];
$excel_array[$i]['dob'] = $value['dob'];
$excel_array[$i]['mobile_no']=$value['mobile_no'];
$k=0;
foreach($value['child_details'] as $data1){
$excel_array[$i]['child_name'.$k]=$data1['child_name'];
$excel_array[$i]['child_date_of_birth'.$k]=$data1['date_of_birth'];
$k++;
}
$sheet->row($i,$excel_array[$i]);
$i++;
```

And this is my column headings

```
$excel_array[1] = ['id','name','dob','mobile_no','child_name','child_dob'];
$sheet->row(1,$excel_array[1]); 
$excel->download('xls');
```

I want to set this column headings dynamically based on the child data..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not simply change the list of elements?

Comment: I can't figure out where you struggle. Can you give more informations ?

Comment: 1st mention which version you are using

Comment: @WaLinke  i want to change excel sheet headings lilke  [id,name,dob,mobileno,child1,dob1,child2,dob2,child3,dob3] here child details should be dynamic.column name may change based on the cound of children..

Comment: @KamleshPaul  Laravel 5.5 and php 7.2

Comment: @Abhijith18p maatwebsite-excel version i m asking as maatwebsite-excel v2 and maatwebsite-excel v3 has so many changes

Comment: @KamleshPaul maatwebsite/excel:2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
 $sheet->row(1, array(
            'id','name','dob','mobile_no','child_name','child_dob'
        ));
 $excel->download('xls');
```

ref link https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/rows.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array and dynamically add your headers names into it.

```
$array = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $nbHeaders; $i++) {
    array_push($array, $value);
}
$sheet->row(1,$array);
```

$nbHeaders is the number of headers you want to add.

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-push.php